# %2F and / in wordpress

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with `/`'s in my urls being translated to `%2F` on links that I post on external sites such as Facebook.

This is an example of how the link should look

http://aflaya.com/?page_id=164/%d7%90%d7%a4%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%91%d7%9e%d7%a7%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%a2%d7%91%d7%95%d7%93%d7%94/%d7%9c%d7%90%d7%aa%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a4%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%90%d7%99%d7%9f-%d7%97%d7%95%d7%a9-%d7%98%d7%9b%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%95%d7%96%d7%94-%d7%92%d7%a0%d7%98%d7%99/

But this is how the link ends up on external sites:

http://aflaya.com/?page_id=164%2F%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%2F%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%98%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%2F

As you can see three `/` characters get translated to `%2F`

When the link is clicked I'd like to be able to translate `%2F` back to a `/` again on my site.

Can I do this with a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` and if so how?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I don't think I understand.

Comment: when i post link in facebook or some forum it's replace to %2F, but it's get me forum main page not post page.
i want via htaccess change %2F to / .

Comment: Are you pasting these urls or is some application pasting them automatically on your behalf?

Comment: or direct copy past, or just via facebook like.
facebook or some forums automatic convert to %2F all slashes after domain link.

Answer (score 1):

Decoded link: http://aflaya.com/?page_id=164/אפליה-במקומות-עבודה/לאתיופים-אין-חוש-טכני-וזה-גנטי/

I think you've left off a closing quote so that what should probably be a `title` on a `a` element is now part of `the_permalink()` in your theme's `loop.php`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp / and %2F are equivalent to the browser. You don't need to rewrite %2F into /, it would be entirely superflous. If you need to do something with the URL in the backend, you can decode the string using url_decode (http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

My guess is you did something wrong when inserting these links. If you tell us more about how you did it, we may be able to help.

Comment: thanks for replay. it's not just url missing, when i do copy past via adres bar. maybe its config of web server?

Comment: Could I see how you've inserted the links into your website, i.e. the <a href="#">-tag.

Comment: as i write, i just take the link from browser and past it to facebook or forum.
it's simple copy past. I think you didn't understand, problem is in the wordpress or server. 
server didn't convert %2F to /. try to click on both links. you will see two different links.

Comment: I told you that if you wanted to do something programmatically with these links you should use url_decode(). The reason I thought that the URL was not right was because the parameters usually come dead last in a URL, and if you pass parameters query style you don't also do it "pretty url"-style. e.g. example.com?id=159/username/anon like you seem to do.

Comment: I am sorry but your questions are very bad. How can I understand a question like that?